# how can i combined the framework and installer in single msi using wix

Tags: .net, deployment, wix, windows-installer, installation

how can i combined the framework and installer in single msi using wix.

reply me soon

Samir

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually install your application and the .NET framework from a single MSI. You have to [create a bootstrapper to install .NET](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_dotnet.htm). However, you could bundle everything in a self-extracting archive that automatically runs the bootstrapper after extraction.

I can't recommend a specific tool because I have not done this myself, but googling [self-extracting archive setup.exe](http://www.google.com/search?q=self-extracting+archive+setup.exe) gives a numer of leads. Specifically, take a look at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151403/what-is-a-good-free-utility-to-create-a-self-extracting-executable-with-an-embedd).