# How to create SFX self executing or Bootstrapper setup with .NET

Tags: .net, setup-project, self-extracting, sfx

How to build the setup similar to [microsoft's dotnet 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21) which is [SFX self executing setup](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/0/f/60fc5854-3cb8-4892-b6db-bd4f42510f28/dotnetfx35.exe).

So which will have the `company information`, and `version info`, etc of the project's `setup.exe` into the final `sfx file`.

Also this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151403/what-is-a-good-free-utility-to-create-a-self-extracting-executable-with-an-embedd) is suggests using `IExpress` but the file information is not what my project is having in `setup.exe`.

> If there is some in-built solution in .NET Framework, I would like to use that first.

Also you can suggest other approach if creating `self-executing SFX` setup is not possible in `.NET Framework`.

**Main purpose is having self-executing SFX file with file information defined by me only.**

Thanks

Comment: Add a Setup and Deployment project to your solution.

Comment: @hanspassant I have the msi file and setup.exe and I want to create one file which would extract it self and run setup.exe and that single should have file details as setup.exe has in its file properties.

Comment: I have checked the dotnet setup from microsoft, its file properties > Archive tab, mentions 7-zip sfx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done with a custom EXE bootstrapper. There is no built-in support for it.

Most commercial setup authoring tools offer this feature even in their most basic versions. If you don't want a different setup authoring tool, you will need to write the bootstrapper yourself or use something like IExpress.

Comment: Can u provide some implementations details or links.. For what u mean to say.. And free tool is more prefable.

Comment: I'm not sure what details I could offer. Like I mentioned, it's a custom EXE. You write it and it does whatever you want it to do.

Comment: I got what you meant, create custom installer for various purpose as I need, thanx for helping and guiding.. :D